SpeechRecognizer from Azure SDK for Javascript not working on Android devices
I have implemented a speech to text recognition (from microphone) using Azure Speech Service.
The speech recognition code is implemented in javascript for browsers and works fine if the webpage is open on a desktop computer.
However if the webpage is open on an Android mobile device it does not work.
Although the SpeechRecognizer is correctly instantiated and the mobile device indicates the microphone is active it looks the microphone does not emit any sound so the recognizer is just waiting - no events are raised during that waiting.
Also there are no errors indicated during that waiting.
Here is the code snippet from my implementation:
function startSpeechRecognition(language) {
    const speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(key_xxx, sReg_yyy);
    speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = language;
    const audioConfig = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
    var myRecognizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    myRecognizer.recognized = (recognizer, event) => {
        switch (event.result.reason) {
            case SpeechSDK.ResultReason.NoMatch:
                break;
            case SpeechSDK.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
                onRecognizedText(speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage, event.result.text);
                break;
            case SpeechSDK.ResultReason.Canceled:
                const cancellation = SpeechSDK.CancellationDetails.fromResult(event.result);
                console.log(`CANCELED: Reason=${cancellation.reason}`);
                if (cancellation.reason == SpeechSDK.CancellationReason.Error) {
                    console.log(`CANCELED: ErrorCode=${cancellation.ErrorCode}`);
                    console.log(`CANCELED: ErrorDetails=${cancellation.errorDetails}`);
                }
                recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
                break;
        }
    };

    myRecognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync(() => { }, e => console.error(e));
}

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong?

I tried a Javascript code to connect with an Android mobile device using my IPv4 address from my desktop computer like http://<your_IPv4 address>:3000/. I got this output in my Android mobile device in the browser, you can see in these images 1 and 2.

You can get your IPv4 address on Windows by running ipconfig in the Command Prompt.

I successfully converted the Azure speech to text on the webpage on my desktop computer and Android mobile device.
Code :
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const speechsdk = require('microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });

const speechKey = '<speech_key>';
const serviceRegion = '<speech_region>';

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.post('/', upload.single('audio-file'), (req, res) => {
    if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded.');
    }

    try {
        const speechConfig = speechsdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(speechKey, serviceRegion);
        speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = 'en-US';
        const audioConfig = speechsdk.AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(req.file.buffer);
        const speechRecognizer = new speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

        speechRecognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(result => {
            fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'templates', 'result.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(`Error reading result template: ${err.message}`);
                }
                const resultHtml = data.replace('<%= text %>', result.text || 'No speech recognized');
                res.send(resultHtml);
            });
        }, error => {
            res.status(500).send(`Error during recognition: ${error.message}`);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(`Error processing request: ${e.message}`);
    }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'templates', 'index.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(`Error reading index template: ${err.message}`);
        }
        res.send(data);
    });
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

templates/index.html :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Speech to Text</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload Audio File</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="audio-file" accept="audio/*" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Transcribe">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

templates/result.html :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Transcription Result</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Transcription Result</h1>
    <p><%= text %></p>
</body>
</html>

package.json :
{
    "name": "speech-recognition-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Azure speech to text",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.19.2",
        "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
        "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk": "^1.38.0",
        "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
        "path": "^0.12.7"
    }
}

Output :
The following code ran successfully as below,

Webpage Output in my Desktop computer :
I got the below webpage on my Desktop computer. I clicked on Choose File to select a .wav file and clicked on Transcribe as shown below,

I got the text output with the above audio file.

On Windows, I got my IPv4 Address by running ipconfig in the Command Prompt as below,

I took the IPv4 Address from Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi as shown below.

Webpage Output in my  Android mobile device:
I got the below webpage on my Android mobile device. I clicked on Choose File to select a .wav file and clicked on Transcribe as shown below,
http://<your_IPv4 address>:3000/

Note : Ensure your desktop computer and Android mobile device use the same Wi-Fi network.

I got the text output with the above audio file.


Your example code makes the transcription from a file which is not problematic. The problem I have reported is related to a speech recognition from a microphone. I believe, if you change the code to use speechsdk.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput(); you will run to the same problem as described.

@OndrejUzovic I will try and update.
